# How to pass bash variables (passwords) to IRSSI config file?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, mutt, irssi

I'm using IRSSI and I wonder how can I pass my IRC channel's passwords to the IRSSI config file (`~/.irssi/config`) without writing them directly in the file.

In Mutt I've an awk command that queries a local file in my encrypted home folder, something like this:

```
set my_pass1=`awk '/fradeve_gmail:/ {print $2}' ~/.mutt/muttpass`
set my_pass2=`awk '/fradeve_inventati:/ {print $2}' ~/.mutt/muttpass`
```

Is there a similar solution for IRSSI?

PS: obviously I **don't** want to keep the IRSSI config file in my encrypted home :)

Comment: You could keep your irssi config in the same encrypted location.

Comment: Why do you "obviously" not want to store the irssi config in the encrypted space? You could symlink it to the irssi config directory.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you store your passwords? If you just have them in the `autosendcmd`, you could do the same trick you do with `awk`.

See http://irssi.org/beginner/#c3 for an example:

```
/NETWORK ADD -autosendcmd "/^msg nickserv ident pass;wait 2000" OFTC
```

Comment: could you expand your answer a little bit more?, I've not find a way to do it with autosendcmd =/

Comment: See edit - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the exact same problem - it seems you can't easily pass bash variables to the irssi config.
Storing passwords in plaintext files or environment variables wouldn't be a good idea in the first place.

In case you are connecting to freenode you could use either [SASL](http://freenode.net/sasl/) or [CERTFP](http://freenode.net/certfp/).
[Here's](http://pbrisbin.com/posts/irssi/) a tutorial that shows how to set up SASL (scroll down to the scripts section).

Answer (score 0):

On servers that use NickServ or another Bot which you need to message to identify yourself you can use the following:

1. Create a shell script that outputs the message you need to send to the bot, save it to your irssi config folder and make it executable. In the case of NickServ:

```
    echo "IDENTIFY $(command that returns nick) $(command that returns password)"
```

2. Enter the following on your `autosendcmd` for your connection substituting script-name by the name of the script you saved previously:

```
    /EXEC - -msg NickServ ./script_name
```

When you connect to the server the `autosendcmd` will execute your shell script and send its output as a message to NickServ.

I'm using a Mac so my nick and password are encrypted and saved on my keychain. The command I use to retrieve them are:

- Nick:

```
/usr/bin/security find-generic-password -l <keychain_password_name> | grep acct | cut -d '"' -f 4
```

- Password:

```
/usr/bin/security find-generic-password -wl <keychain_password_name>
```

This way there won't be any plain text passwords on your irssi config file.