# How to store confidential info whilst using dot files framework

Tags: passwords, git, irssi, dotfiles, freenode

I'm trying to come up with a strategy to store my dotfiles in Git. So far, I've create a [dotfiles repo on GitHub](https://github.com/MasterRoot24/dotfiles) and I've thrown together an install script which simply clones the repo, then symlinks each of the files into my `~` directory.

However I'm struggling to come up with a way of storing confidential information in my dotfiles, but at the same time making sure that none of it gets committed into Git.

For example, I have my Irssi config file, in which I have the following:

```
chatnets = {
  Freenode = {
  type = "IRC";
  autosendcmd = "/msg nickserv identify PASSWORD ; wait 2000";
  ...
```

Now that I am version controlling this dot file, I can't store my password directly in this file. This means that every time I start Irssi, I have to manually `identify` with NickServ as `PASSWORD` is obviously not my NickServ password.

I've tried to see if there's a way to include a secured, non-version controlled file into the Irssi config, but I can't find any solutions for this.

How should I store my dotfiles in such a way that I can store confidential information such as passwords required by the dotfiles outside of Git?

Related, but no real solution:
[How to pass bash variables (passwords) to IRSSI config file?](https://superuser.com/questions/376514/how-to-pass-bash-variables-passwords-to-irssi-config-file)
Using SASL for Irssi isn't really a convenient option as it's yet another thing to setup on a new system and I'm trying to make the installation process as simple as possible.

Comment: How can I improve my question to get more help on this?

Comment: Just added [the issue on github][https://github.com/irssi/irssi/issues/246] to add this feature.

Comment: @El_Hoy thanks for raising that issue, but that link looks to be broken. Here's a working link to the issue on GitHub https://github.com/irssi/irssi/issues/246

Answer (score 0):

Many programs support putting shell commands into their configuration files in some way.  For example, I have this in my `.neomuttrc`:

```
set my_fastmail_pass="`gpg -dq ~/.config/neomutt/fastmail-password.gpg`"
```

I think you can [do something similar with Irssi](https://superuser.com/a/1496582).  Alternatively, you can use [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) for files that contain secrets.  This way, the whole file is encrypted.